# System of linear equations in fortran using DGESV

Tags: fortran, lapack

I am new to fortran and are trying to solve a set of linear equations using DGESV. I am trying to make the simplest program possible just to get the method running, but are getting this error message:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x106cef092
#1  0x106cee3b0
#2  0x7fff8dda9f19
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Here is the code:

```
   program linearEqSolver

   implicit none
   EXTERNAL         DGESV

   integer, parameter :: N = 3, NRHS = 1, LDA = N,LDB = N
   integer :: INFO
   real, dimension (N) :: IPIV, b
   real, dimension (N,N) :: A


   b = (/ 4, -6, 7/)
   A(:,1) = (/ 1, 1, -1/)
   A(:,2) = (/ 1, -2, 3/)
   A(:,3) = (/ 2, 3, 1/)

   CALL DGESV( N, NRHS, A, LDA, IPIV, B, LDB, INFO )

   end program
```

Comment: DGESV uses double precision floats - so specify real*8 (or 'double precision') for IPIV, b and A.

Comment: Or use SGESV. Or use a Fortran 90+ generic interface and just call GESV. That's what I am doing. It is much safer.

Comment: Thank you both! The first option did work!

Comment: See point 3 in the answer in the duplicate link.